# How to migrate from old PHP database handler library to PDO without any code breaking?

Tags: php, design-patterns, pdo

I used the `AdoDb` database handler library for my project, now I want to migrate to `PDO` but I don't want that whole project stop working what can I do?

I used about 10 methods of that handler (and use simple query that work `PDO` too) so I found two solutions for this:

1- Extends `PDO` class and add the `AdoDB` methods signature to it and fix it to work with `PDO`.

2- Wrap the `PDO` class and add those methods.

What is the best solution to do this, and should I consider doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, your question is about extending or wrapping. It is generally good practice not to extend classes you don't own. For instance, any change in the PDO class could, unpredictable, break your extended class. You do not control the changes. So since you don't own the PDO class I would suggest wrapping it.

Make sure however you use all the benefits of the PDO class. Otherwise you will only make your code more complex without any improvements.

Comment: Yeah wrap, create your own class base and just switch them.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any functional/browser tests for this project? If so, copy the project to your dev machine, then modify each AdoDB call to the PDO equivalent, and repeat until your tests pass.

Indeed, you could fix PDO to look like AdoDB, but only do this if you think the methods you need map cleanly onto PDO. Fixing all use cases should be quite quick, given you can just do a global search in your project.

If you do not have any functional tests for this project, consider writing some - they will help given you confidence you have not broken something when undertaking large-scale refactoring of this kind. Of course, you should have a test for every action in your project, so generally it is the case that more tests = better protection from regression.

Comment: thanks for your advise. my application has many places that use old library and it's hard to modify them all. so for now I want to wrap pdo class and refactor codes later. the problem is that not only pdo class need to change but also what it return like statement(when select from db it return another class..) need to be wrap :(